# How to empty a file with terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, files, scripting, null

All my sites include a script that saves in a file all the fake google IPs that are not in google IP range.

Then with a script once a day I add all the IPs to the firewall.

```
while read line; do sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='$line' reject"; done < /var/www/html/function_global/ip_add_fwd.txt
```

But after that, I have to manually reload an empty ip_add_fwd.txt file on the server, because I don't know how to empty the file via terminal... help... please...

If I could automatically empty the file, I might as well put everything in a crontab, I guess... and forget about it...

---

And if I want to make a script?

Comment: Why don't you just use fail2ban?

Comment: Because I don't know how to add a file list to file2ban... :( I'm a php programmer, not a server expert... :( I found this line online...

Comment: How did you determine that any particular IP address was a fake google IP?

Comment: For years I have been monitoring and verifying all the ip that enter my server claiming to be google, the real google ip ranges that scan my server are these: 66.249.64.0/19 66.102.0.0/20 64.233.160.0/19 34.64.0.0 / 10 216.58.192.0/19 74.125.0.0/16, everything else is rubbish ...

Comment: What do you mean by "everything else"? You mean IPs appearing with a user agent claiming to be a Google spider, but not from these subnets?

Comment: Yes... just that

Comment: Not posting as an answer, because this isn't the question you asked... why are you blocking these IPs? Is the load on your server so bad that it's worth your time to bother? Why not put a rule in place denying any traffic to that user agent if not coming from one of the allowed IPs once and be done with it?

Comment: The reason I want to block them is because very often someone tries to clone my entire sites, and they probably try to do the same. It happens so often that I have created a fail2ban rule that says that if in less than a minute an ip receives more than 60 404 (missing images or deleted pages, etc ...) it is blocked, and it often happens that this rule is applied. Unfortunately it may happen that this rule also involves search engine spiders such as google, so I preferred to check the IPs one by one for a long time, until I identified those ranges of IPs.

Comment: But actually more and more often I realize that outside of the google ip renge, the ip that are detected are all ip of scammers who try to visit thousands of pages in a minute or enter sql in my search fields, etc ... so maybe it's worth automating the process ...

Answer (score 3):

I normally use option **3** <sup>(edited to be more universal among shells)</sup>

1. ```
   cat /dev/null > yourFile
   ```
2. ```
   dd if=/dev/null of=yourFile
   ```
3. ```
   : > yourFile
   ```

Credit: [5 Ways to Empty or Delete a Large File Content in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/empty-delete-file-content-linux/) on TecMint.

Comment: I try this... while read line; do sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='$line' reject"; done < /var/www/html/function_global/ip_add_fwd.txt > /var/www/html/function_global/ip_add_fwd.txt
but i think it emptyed my file without doing the while...

Comment: Be aware that option 3 (`> yourfilename`) is not going to work on `zsh`, as that causes it to read from `stdin` until `EOF` is supplied

Comment: If there are 5, then please provide also the two remaining options too :)

Comment: Option 3 edited to be more universal among shells. Hope the poster does not mind. Thanks @Panki for pointing it out!

Comment: Thanks, @LinuxSecurityFreak, and Panki. Glad you guys spotted and corrected that.